# Having trouble committing to git with Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

When I created the project I was able to commit about 2 times, but now it doesn't allow me. The button is grayed out like this:

[image]

All I've done was edit the code in my project. I got out of Visual Studio and the next day I came back and it's not working. How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  Have you installed the latest update?  They contain valuable bug fixes.

Comment: @EdwardThomson 2015 version. Where can I find the latest update?

Comment: @templateboy Visual Studio Update 3, June 27th, 2016: https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug that was fixed in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2:  briefly, Visual Studio spawns a background thread to check the status of your repository.  If that thread throws an exception for some reason, Visual Studio will never report the status.  (And, consequently, will not let you commit your changes.)

Installing the latest Update 3 *should* fix this problem:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs

(And of course, @VonC has the quite correct workaround that the command line is immune to such issues.)

Comment: This update seems to be huge. It's been over 20 minutes and it's not even close to done. Is this normal or could it be my internet connection which is bad?

Comment: They are quite huge, there are a _lot_ of bug fixes, plus new features since 2015 RTM.

Answer (score 2):

When the GUI fails, revert back to the command line.

Unzip the latest [git-for-windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) like [`PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.9.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want (like  `C:\git\2.9.0`), and add it to your path (`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\git\2.9.0\bin`)

Then do in a CMD:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git status
git branch
# try and modify files
git status
# Check if Visual Studio authorizes you to commit
# if not
git add .
git commit -m "changes"
```

Comment: @templateboy yes, the same command prompt CMD where you set your `C:\git\2.9.0\bin` to your `%PATH%`.