# Git bash is not showing for another useraccount on my windows

Tags: windows, git, bash

I am using two accounts in my windows computer and both the accounts having same administrator privileges.

I have installed Git tool in my computer when I logged into first account.

But after I switched to second account I can not able to see the Git options on right clicking in the git local branch folder.

How this behavior I am looking?

Should I install git for every individual User account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How this behavior I am looking?

The config are probably global, which means they are stored in `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`, with `%USERPROFILE%` being different for each user

> Should I install git for every individual User account?

You don't, as long as your `%PATH%` include `<git>/bin`

I personally don't use the setup, only a self-extracting archive: [**`PortableGit-2.10.1-64-bit.7z.exe`**](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.10.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.10.1-64-bit.7z.exe) (as [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38279142/6309)).
But that would not add the "`Git bash here`" contextual menu entry in the Windows Explorer though: for that, you need to install Git "**for all users**" with [`Git-2.10.1-64-bit.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.10.1.windows.1/Git-2.10.1-64-bit.exe) (not just "for current user")

Comment: Your suggestion is looking great, and when I am trying to do the fix which you told first I can not able to see git bash still.

Comment: @BKumar what is your PATH? bash.exe should be in there.

Comment: @BKumar Or do you mean you cannot see git bash in the Windows contextual menu? (right click on a folder in the windows Explorer)

Comment: Yes, when I right click in the existing local branch folder I can not able to see the git bash option here.

Comment: @BKumar in that case, yes, use the Git setup and install again Git with the second account: only the setup.exe does add the contextual menu.

Comment: @BKumar I have edited the answer: only *one* installation should have been enough, provided you select the option "for all users" after launching the setup `Git-2.10.1-64-bit.exe`